# ListBox constant CPU usage

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I noticed my application is using about 15% of the CPU constantly when I have a ListBox visible.

I tried using Redgate's ANTS Performance Profiler but I did not manage to find the origin of this CPU-usage. Nothing is being updated so I think this is very strange.

Here is the XAML-code for the ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MusicList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" MouseDoubleClick="MusicList_MouseDoubleClick" PreviewMouseWheel="MusicList_PreviewMouseWheel" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="MusicList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"  TextSearch.TextPath="name" KeyDown="MusicList_KeyDown" Background="#3F181818" Margin="0,175,0,0" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" BorderBrush="#FF282828">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="88">
                <Border Height="64" Width="64" Margin="12,12,0,12">
                    <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding Path=album.albumart, IsAsync=True}"/>

                </Border>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name, IsAsync=True, Mode=OneTime}"
                               Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="300" Height="40" 
                               TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=album.name, IsAsync=True, Mode=OneTime}" 
                               Margin="10,-15,0,0" Width="300" Height="20" 
                               TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                               FontSize="14" Opacity="0.49" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=artistname, IsAsync=True, Mode=OneTime}" 
                               Margin="10,2,0,0" Width="300"
                               TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               FontSize="12" Opacity="0.49" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I do have about 500 items in the listbox itself, but I assume DataViritualization is on, since scrolling makes it look like new items are being drawed.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: *I assume DataViritualization is on*... it shouldn't be unless you put it on. Either way, a standard `ListBox` won't consume CPU power constantly, so you clearly have something else going on in your project. What happens when you run the application and then click the pause button in Visual Studio? If it is your code that is using the CPU cycles, then the debugger will jump to that code.

Comment: @Sheridan When I press the pause button in Visual Studio, a new tab opens and this message shows: "The current thread is not running any code or the call stack could not be obtained"

Comment: Then what makes you think that your application is taking the CPU cycles? Are you sure it's not just the VS Debugger using them?

Comment: @Sheridan Since running the executable without Visual Studio gives the same result, it can't be Visual Studio creating this problem. And cause the only time it happens, is when I have that listbox visible in the Frame I use to navigate between my pages.